# why preloader isn't working on my website?

Tags: html, css, loader, preloader

I am trying to add preloader to my HTML pages but it isn't showing any preloader? I even copy-pasted the codes and CSS from web resources like codeopen but it isn't showing anything. If someone experienced the same and tackled the situation then help me.

Comment: Please post the code you tried or at least the link to the codepen or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" as="script">
```

Will Preload an javascript file with the as html tag. Don't forget that!

Then later in your html, it will be used at preload cache often.